# What Jfrog Artifactories types (Docker, Helm, General) needed for Kuberentes cluster using Rancher?

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, artifactory, rancher

I am going to create Kubernetes cluster from scratch with Rancher and I would like to have jfrog artifactory for my container images.

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the differnet artifacoties types and which one I actually need:

Jfrog Artifactory - Package Type: Docker

Jfrog Artifactory - Package Type: Helm

Jfrog Artifactory - Package Type: General

1. what is the use of each type?
2. is the fact that Jfrog Artifactory is with Package Type: Docker makes him "Docker repository" that can store container images that can be pulled/pushed with the Docker client?
3. for the Kubernetes cluster - should I have 2 Artifacotries at the end:
   one of type Helm - in order to save all the deployment files
   one of type Docker - in order to save all the container images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the [jfrog container registry](https://jfrog.com/download-jfrog-container-registry/) flavor of Artifactory, which supports Docker, Helm registries and Generic repositories.

1. This is a single server that is intended for exactly what you need as a single source for your Kubernetes deployments: The container images (Docker), the Helm charts and any other generic files you might like to manage.
2. Yes. Your Artifactory is your Docker registry.
3. No need. A single Artifactory can be used for both.

I suggest you follow the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Container+Registry) on this.

Comment: Hi Eldad, thanks for your answer. this is my confusion, what makes a repository a container registry? just the Package type Docker? is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The Docker type repository in Artifactory implements the Docker API so you can designate this as your registry and do all `docker pull/push` commands with it. Same for Helm.